# Manual Judgment stage fail to run due to java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find stage builder for type manualJudgment

Tags: spinnaker

I'm running spinnaker on local kubernetes cluster (minikube). I followed a instruction from https://github.com/kenzanlabs/spinikube to start a spinnaker with some configurate changed to suit my environment.

When I tried to start a pipeline which contains manual judgment stage but the stage is never triggered.

Here is a what I found in the orca stacktrace.

> 2016-10-07 04:05:06.024 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] c.n.spinnaker.orca.batch.StageBuilder    : Exception occurred while building flow builder
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find stage builder for type manualJudgment
>         at com.netflix.spinnaker.orca.batch.StageBuilder$_buildDependentStages_closure7.doCall(StageBuilder.groovy:190)
>         at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor510.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>         at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:292)
>         at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1015)
>         at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
>         at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:439)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1379)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1372)
>         at com.netflix.spinnaker.orca.batch.StageBuilder.buildDependentStages(StageBuilder.groovy:182)
>         at com.netflix.spinnaker.orca.batch.StageBuilder.buildParallel(StageBuilder.groovy:162)
>         at com.netflix.spinnaker.orca.batch.StageBuilder.build(StageBuilder.groovy:88)
>         at com.netflix.spinnaker.orca.batch.StageBuilder$_buildDependentStages_closure7.doCall(StageBuilder.groovy:217)
>         at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor510.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>         at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:292)
>         at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1015)
>         at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
>         at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:439)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1379)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1372)
>         at com.netflix.spinnaker.orca.batch.StageBuilder.buildDependentStages(StageBuilder.groovy:182)
>         at com.netflix.spinnaker.orca.batch.StageBuilder.buildParallel(StageBuilder.groovy:162)
>         at com.netflix.spinnaker.orca.batch.StageBuilder.build(StageBuilder.groovy:88)
>         at com.netflix.spinnaker.orca.pipeline.PipelineJobBuilder.createStage(PipelineJobBuilder.groovy:121)
>         at com.netflix.spinnaker.orca.pipeline.PipelineJobBuilder.buildFlowParallel(PipelineJobBuilder.groovy:114)
>         at com.netflix.spinnaker.orca.pipeline.PipelineJobBuilder.build(PipelineJobBuilder.groovy:49)
>         at com.netflix.spinnaker.orca.pipeline.PipelineJobBuilder.build(PipelineJobBuilder.groovy)
>         at com.netflix.spinnaker.orca.pipeline.ExecutionStarter.createJob(ExecutionStarter.groovy:96)
>         at com.netflix.spinnaker.orca.pipeline.ExecutionStarter.startExecution(ExecutionStarter.groovy:65)
>         at com.netflix.spinnaker.orca.pipeline.ExecutionStarter.start(ExecutionStarter.groovy:61)
>         at com.netflix.spinnaker.orca.pipeline.ExecutionStarter$start.call(Unknown Source)
>         at com.netflix.spinnaker.orca.controllers.OperationsController.startPipeline(OperationsController.groovy:169)
>         at com.netflix.spinnaker.orca.controllers.OperationsController.this$2$startPipeline(OperationsController.groovy)
>         at com.netflix.spinnaker.orca.controllers.OperationsController$this$2$startPipeline$1.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
>         at com.netflix.spinnaker.orca.controllers.OperationsController.orchestrate(OperationsController.groovy:111)
>         at com.netflix.spinnaker.orca.controllers.OperationsController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c9607418.invoke()
>         at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:649)
>         at com.netflix.spinnaker.orca.controllers.OperationsController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e00c860d.orchestrate()
>         at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor523.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
>         at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:775)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:965)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:867)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:841)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>         at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:300)
>         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
>         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
>         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>         at com.netflix.spinnaker.orca.web.config.WebConfiguration$1.doFilter(WebConfiguration.groovy:76)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:83)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:300)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>         at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:103)
>         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>         at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
>         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>         at com.netflix.spinnaker.fiat.shared.FiatAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(FiatAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>         at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
>         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>         at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:77)
>         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>         at javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter.call(Unknown Source)
>         at com.netflix.spinnaker.filters.AuthenticatedRequestFilter.doFilter(AuthenticatedRequestFilter.groovy:108)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>         at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>         at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
>         at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
>         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: OK, It works now. I have to enable echo in orga.yaml.

Answer (score 0):

1. Upgrade spinnaker to a later version
2. check the `halconfig`
3. Is the stage enabled in the orchestration micro services yaml file `orca.yaml`??

please let us know